# R Adding random sample

Tags: r, random-seed

I have text file like

```
1 2
1 3
1 2 3 5 11
1 2 3 5 12
.
.
up to 18k rows
```

and I want to generate random sample between 0, and 1, like

```
1 0.31 2 0.15
1 0.93 3 0.84
1 0.62 2 0,76 3 0.34 5 0.31 11 0.11
1 0.55 2 0.54 3 0.62 5 0.44 12 0.54
.
.
```

I used the follow code

```
Lines1 <- readLines("Example30v2.txt") 
lst1 <- lapply(Lines1,function(x)
  { x1 <-scan(text=x,nmax=1000,quiet=TRUE);
    dat1<-as.data.frame(matrix(x1,ncol=1,byrow=TRUE))
  })
nm1 <- (unlist(lapply(lst1,`[`,1),use.names=FALSE))

set.seed(48) 
vec1 <- sample(seq(0,1,by=0.01),length(nm1),replace = TRUE) 

names(vec1) <- nm1 
res <- sapply(lst1,function(x)
  { x$V2 <- vec1[as.character(x$V1)];
    paste(as.vector(t(x)),collapse=" ")
  }) 

##Save the output in a txt file
 fileConn <- file("unExample30v2.txt")
 writeLines(res,fileConn)
 close(fileConn)
```

but it gave me unique value for each number.

```
1 0.58 2 0.03
1 0.58 3 0.38
1 0.58 2 0.03 3 0.38 5 0.99 11 0.03
1 0.58 2 0.03 3 0.38 5 0.99 12 0.91
```

Comment: I see what is happening now, but don't quite see how to fix it yet :)

Comment: You are duplicating the names that you use to look up the values, so it is always looking up the same value. Can't see how change your code to make that work, it would be easier to use another approach.

Comment: until `names(vec1) <- nm1 ` if I run `> vec1` I got the result that I want it. but after `res <- sapply(lst1,function(x) {x$V2 <- vec1[as.character(x$V1)];paste(as.vector(t(x)),collapse=" ")}) ` I got the problem. when I run `> vec1` I see each value got unique prob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set.seed(1);
system('cat -vet Example30v2.txt;');
## 1 2$
## 1 3$
## 1 2 3 5 11$
## 1 2 3 5 12$
input <- as.matrix(unname(read.table('Example30v2.txt',sep=' ',fill=T)));
input;
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]    1    2   NA   NA   NA
## [2,]    1    3   NA   NA   NA
## [3,]    1    2    3    5   11
## [4,]    1    2    3    5   12
output <- matrix(rbind(c(t(input)),round(ifelse(is.na(c(t(input))),NA,runif(nrow(input)*ncol(input))),2)),nrow(input),byrow=T);
output;
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
## [1,]    1 0.27    2 0.37   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
## [2,]    1 0.90    3 0.94   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
## [3,]    1 0.21    2 0.18    3 0.69    5 0.38   11  0.77
## [4,]    1 0.50    2 0.72    3 0.99    5 0.38   12  0.78
writeLines(apply(output,1,function(x) paste(na.omit(x),collapse=' ')),'unExample30v2.txt');
system('cat -vet unExample30v2.txt;');
## 1 0.27 2 0.37$
## 1 0.9 3 0.94$
## 1 0.21 2 0.18 3 0.69 5 0.38 11 0.77$
## 1 0.5 2 0.72 3 0.99 5 0.38 12 0.78$
```

Comment: I faced hard time every time I need to use `r` to generate data. I spent 20 hours trying to generate this. You save me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a random sample of size 20 in the set [1,0] you can use following code

```
  u <- runif(20)
```

when you call it for each number each time you should get different values.

you will need to loop on your numbers in the vector and call  runif(yournumber)

[image]

Comment: I did edit vec1 in my code to `vec1 <- runif(length(nm1), .01, .99)` still got the same prob for each number

Comment: you have a text file  that has some numbers could you explain what do you want to do with this file ? Because generating random sample in R can be done using many  built-in density functions. Unless your file has a pattern then you need to tell us what is this pattern.

Comment: I just want to add random probability (between 0,1) for each entry (integer value)

Comment: You can just copy the first few lines he shows in the text into a file and use that. Then you don't have to run the whole thing, just up to the res assignment. If you print out the res vector and the vec1 vector you can see what is going wrong.

Comment: You need to  recall runif(n,0.01,0.99) for each number . Use a loop to do so.